# Odd behavior in code block

Tags: bug

I was writing an answer that consisted of one code block starting with this line:

```
greetings = ["hello","hi","hey"]
```

When I posted the answer, it was garbled (strangely, the preview area displayed correctly.)

This specific line of code somehow confuses the parser, perhaps?

EDIT:

Here's a screenshot of the post before I hit "Save":

[image: Screenshot before submitting]

And here's the garbled result:

[image: Screenshot of garbled result]

Comment: Maybe you should post a screenshot?

Comment: @vaultah will do.

Comment: It looks like "greetings"'is being taken as a, well, greeting and removed along with the leading spaces.

Comment: No greetings for your answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989 (I have fixed it just by using the pre and code tags)

Comment: @Rizier123 that explains it, thanks!

Comment: Which is why you should post non-code-only answers.

Comment: related:[Edit source differs from question view? Or are we each other's friends now?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123981/edit-source-differs-from-question-view-or-are-we-each-others-friends-now)

Comment: @TZHX ah the automatic quality filter.  classic.